# Python Dictionary Not Printing as I Expected

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops

I've been working on a python script where, given a list consisting of three lists, it will create a dictionary that will store key-value pairs where the keys represent the (row, column) of the list as tuples, and the corresponding values are the list values for that specific position. Here is what I have:

```
EMPTY = None

board_2 = [
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]
    ]

board_position = {}
for row in board_2:
    for cell in row:
        board_position[(board_2.index(row), row.index(cell))] = board_2[board_2.index(row)][row.index(cell)]

print(board_position)
```

I expect that it would print out a dictionary where all nine keys would have `None` as their values; yet instead, I just get this in return:

```
{(0, 0): None}
```

It seems that the dictionary stopped after given just the first key-value pair, and ignoring everything afterwards. I assumed that there was something wrong in my code, like my logic being off perhaps in the nested loop. Yet incredibly, when I decided to create another version of `board_2`, this time `board_1`, where `board_1` had different values in the lists, my code seemed to work:

Input:

```
board_1 = [
   ['00', '01', '02'],
   ['10', '11', '12'],
   ['20', '21', '22']
   ]

board_position = {}
for row in board_1:
    for cell in row:
        board_position[(board_1.index(row), row.index(cell))] = board_1[board_1.index(row)][row.index(cell)]

print(board_position)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 0): '00', (0, 1): '01', (0, 2): '02', (1, 0): '10', (1, 1): '11', (1, 2): '12', (2, 0): '20', (2, 1): '21', (2, 2): '22'}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
```

This, now, seems to work. The only difference I can see between the two board versions would be that the values inside the lists differ; but I don't see why that would matter. I'm aware that if a preexisting key is appended to a dictionary the dictionary would update the existing key with the new value. But it looks like the keys are different; the values, though are the same. Am I missing something here, is my code wrong, or is there something else I should now about python dictionaries? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index returns the *first* occurence of a value inside a list - hence all your `EMPTY` are found at position 0. And added as `(0,0)`. You overwrite the same key over and over - so you only have this key in your resulting dictionary.

Your second example has all different values, so `index` works - but its very time consuming to get all those indexes.

It is better to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
EMPTY = None

board_2 = [
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
    [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]
    ]

board_1 = [
   ['00', '01', '02'],
   ['10', '11', '12'],
   ['20', '21', '22']
   ]

for b in (board_2, board_1):
    board_position = {}
    for id1, row in enumerate(b):
        for id2,cell in enumerate(row):
            board_position[(id1,id2)] = cell

    print(board_position)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 1): None, (1, 2): None, (0, 0): None, (2, 1): None, (1, 1): None, 
 (2, 0): None, (2, 2): None, (1, 0): None, (0, 2): None}

{(0, 1): '01', (1, 2): '12', (0, 0): '00', (2, 1): '21', (1, 1): '11', 
 (2, 0): '20', (2, 2): '22', (1, 0): '10', (0, 2): '02'}
```

or shorter as dict comprehension:

```
d = { (r,c):cell for r,x in enumerate(board_1) for c,cell in enumerate(x) }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first implementation, all of the rows and cells are the same value, so when you call `list.index`, it grabs the first appearance of the identical sublist. In this case, you'd want to use `enumerate` to record iteration values, like this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(board_1):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        board_position[(i, j)] = cell
```

Comment: `board_1[i][j]` == `cell`

Comment: Ah, I see now; my understanding of how .index() worked was lacking that detail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

THe issue here is the `index` function, it will look through the given list to find the `first` value that matches. When the arrays are empty it is looking for an array of `[None, None, None]`. This will match the `first` row every time! Likewise when finding the index of each element in each row. Its much better practice and more efficient to use a counter:

```
row_pos = 0
for row in board_1:
    cell_pos = 0
    for cell in row:
        board_position[(row_pos, cell_pos)] = board_1[row_pos][cell_pos]
        cell_pos += 1
    row_pos += 1

print(board_position)
```

Comment: There's no point iterating to get `row` and `cell` if you're not going to use them. Just iterate on `range(len(board))` and `range(len(board[0]))` if you want only the indexes.

Comment: True, I was only updating the part of the OP's code that wasn't working however.